# How to disregard all rows after and including a whole row of NAs?

Tags: r

My reason for asking this is because I because I work in a lab in which my co-worker does some analyses in Microsoft-Excel spreadsheets. I sometimes find a Microsoft Excel analytical table at the bottom of the columns of the spreadsheets. I have no trouble reading these spreadsheets into R for my purposes. The pattern is that there will always be at least one whole row of empty cells or NAs in the spreadsheet, so anything following and including a whole row of NAs should not be interpreted into R because it's not raw data.

Imagine a simple a numeric data-frame (df) like this.

I added a "#" to show the rows that I want to exclude.

```
    x  y  z  comments
1   8  5  4     <NA>
2   3  6  5     <NA>
3   7  7  3     <NA>
4   9  3 10     Well
5   4 NA  6     <NA>
6   5  9  8     <NA>
7   1  4  7     Yeah
8  10  2  2     <NA>
9   2 10  9     <NA>
10  6  1  1 I guess 
11 NA NA NA     <NA> # whole row of NAs/empty cells. # exclude
12  8  3  4  Summary # exclude 
13  1  1  2     <NA> # exclude
14 NA NA NA     <NA> # exclude
```

If I just exclude all rows containing NA, I lose a lot of information:

```
print(na.omit(df))
   x y  z comments
4  9 3 10     Well
7  1 4  7     Yeah
10 6 1  1 I guess
```

I don't want to just disregard the comments because they may or may not be complete.

But seeing the whole row of NAs, which in this example case occurs in row 11 signals to exclude the following rows, so the spreadsheet that I want to include, includes this much:

```
    x  y  z comments
1   8  5  4     <NA>
2   3  6  5     <NA>
3   7  7  3     <NA>
4   9  3 10     Well
5   4 NA  6     <NA>
6   5  9  8     <NA>
7   1  4  7     Yeah
8  10  2  2     <NA>
9   2 10  9     <NA>
10  6  1  1 I guess
```

This is just mock data right here, but I have to do this pretty frequently so here is the mock data that I showed you:

```
structure(list(x = c(8, 3, 7, 9, 4, 5, 1, 10, 2, 6, NA, 8, 1, 
NA), y = c(5, 6, 7, 3, NA, 9, 4, 2, 10, 1, NA, 3, 1, NA), z = c(4, 
5, 3, 10, 6, 8, 7, 2, 9, 1, NA, 4, 2, NA), comments = c(NA, NA, 
NA, "Well", NA, NA, "Yeah", NA, NA, "I guess ", NA, "Summary", 
NA, NA)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "comments"), row.names = c(NA, 
14L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I exclude all rows including and following a whole row of NAs (empty cells) in any type of dataframe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `&` to create a logical vector for subsetting the dataset

```
df[!cumsum(Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, is.na))),]
#   x  y  z comments
#1   8  5  4     <NA>
#2   3  6  5     <NA>
#3   7  7  3     <NA>
#4   9  3 10     Well
#5   4 NA  6     <NA>
#6   5  9  8     <NA>
#7   1  4  7     Yeah
#8  10  2  2     <NA>
#9   2 10  9     <NA>
#10  6  1  1 I guess
```

Comment: I was just about to ask you what the "&" did? Thank you for explaining.

Comment: I like this one-liner solution!

Comment: I chose this solution because I like how it does not involve the creation of any new variables in the subsetting. The other solution is very logical in terms of computer science, but this one makes powerful use of wrapping functions. How did you think of this, and can you elaborate on it?

Comment: @xyz123  Thanks, the output of `lapply(df, is.na)` is a `list` of logical vectors checking whether each column value is NA or not.  So, TRUE will correspond to NA and FALSE to non-NA.  By using `Reduce` with `&`, it is reduced to a single logical vector by comparing the corresponding elements of each `list`.  In effect, if a row has all NA, this will return TRUE and all others FALSE.  Wrapping with `cumsum` converts it to numeric vector `cumsum(Reduce('&', lapply(df, is.na)))#
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2`

Comment: @xyz123  Note that all elements before the first row where it is all NA are 0 and others are greater than 0. By negating (`!`), we convert the 0's to TRUE and all others FALSE.  `!cumsum(Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, is.na)))#
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE` which is used for subsetting the rows

Answer (score 2):

One base R option would be to find first compute all row sums of `NA` values, and then check which sums are equal to the number of columns.  Then, find the *first* row having all `NA` values, and then subset your data frame, taking all rows from the beginning up until one minus this first row of all `NA` values.

```
# TRUE if a given row has NA in every column
x <- rowSums(is.na(df)) != ncol(df)

# the row immediately before the FIRST all NA row, or the final row,
# if no rows are all NA
last_row <- ifelse(length(which(!x)) == 0, nrow(df), which(!x)[1] - 1)

# subset the data frame
df[1:last_row, ]
```

### Demo

I updated to cover an edge case where there are no rows in the data frame having all `NA` values.  In this case, the subset should just produce the entire original data frame.

Comment: I think OP also wants to exclude rows that are later than a row with all NA.

Comment: This will only remove the  all NA row and not the ones after it. Can you please update your answer?

Comment: `dat[1:min(which(!rowSums(is.na(dat)) != ncol(dat))) - 1, ]` does the trick I think. Submitted an edit Tim!

Comment: Thank you for your help.